# Lambert W function inequality

Tags: inequality, lambert-w

I'm trying to approximate the number of lottery cards where the probability of the jackpot according to the birthday paradox is not lower than the number of cards divided by the number of all probable lottery variations:

$1 - e^\frac{-n^2}{2M} \ge \frac{n}{M}$,

where $n$ is the number of lottery cards and $M$ is the number of all probable variations. Now reordering this inequality gives:

$\frac{n^2}{2M} - \frac{n^2}{2M}e^\frac{-n^2}{2M} \le \frac{n^3}{2M}$

$\frac{-n^2}{2M}e^\frac{-n^2}{2M} \le \frac{n^2(1-n)}{2M}$

$\frac{-n^2}{2M} \ge W(\frac{n^2(1-n)}{2M})$

Besides not being sure about the direction of the inequality in the last line, I have no clue how to go on with the solution. The number of $M$ is known, $n$ needs to be expressed somehow. I only need hints and keywords on how to move on.

Comment: I wonder if you are not making life more difficult going from the first inequality to the last. By the way, but I don't know how this could help $$1 - e^\frac{-n^2}{2M} = \frac{n}{M}$$ has a solution $$M=\frac{n^2}{W\left(-e^{-n} n\right)+n}$$

Comment: Trouble is, n is the unknown I'd like to express as a function of an already known M.

Comment: First, I think that I had typo's. It should be $$M=\frac{n^2}{2 W\left(-\frac{1}{2} e^{-n/2} n\right)+n}$$ So, you could just consider the problem as the intersection of a well defined function $f(n)$ with an horizontal line. You could even generate table of $f(n)$. I shall follow your post since it is really an interesting problem.

Comment: After graphing the two sides of the first line I got that in case of M = 43.949.268 (90 choose 5 lottery) if n = 2 then the two sides equals, if n > 2 then the LHS is greater. How can this 2 be sorted out?

Comment: By the way, @ClaudeLeibovici, how did you sort you solution out that doesn't contain M in it?

Comment: Solving for $M$ the equation $1 - e^\frac{-n^2}{2M} = \frac{n}{M}$

Comment: First I get $e^{n^2}-e^\frac{1}{2M}=e^{n^2}\frac{n}{M}$, then $e^{n^2}\frac{M-n}{M}=e^\frac{1}{2M}$, then $e^{n^2}\frac{M-n}{2M^2}=\frac{1}{2M}e^\frac{1}{2M}$, which leads me to $\frac{1}{2M}=W(e^{n^2}\frac{M-n}{2n^2})$. Now I get $M=\frac{1}{2W(e^{n^2}\frac{M-n}{2M^2})}$, and I still don't see how you managed to separate M from n in your solution :)